# Batch script to Insert all lines from a text file before occurrence of a specific string

Tags: batch-file

I'm using below code for inserting text contents after a specific line/string is found. How can I modify this code to insert all the lines before the occurrence of line/string in file ?

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /rinc:"string"  test.txt') do (set line_no=%%i)
for /f "skip=%line_no% delims=" %%a in ('type test.txt') do (echo %%a >> output.txt)
```

i.e if `test.txt` contains:

```
abc
def
p q r
u v w
xyz
```

If the the search is for line `p q r`, the output should be:

```
abc
def
```

Comment: You can highlight lines as shown by selecting the required lines and pressing the `{}` buton in the header. It works by indenting by 4 spaces, so you can use that technique too, if you want. I can't format your `output` listing as it makes little sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test if the line matches the sting, if it does, exit loop:

```
@echo off
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type test.txt') do (
    if "%%i" == "p q r" exit /b
    echo %%i
 )
)>output.txt
```

To include everything up to and including the search string, simply swop the `if` statement and the `echo` lines.

```
@echo off
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type test.txt') do (
    echo %%i
    if "%%i" == "p q r" exit /b
 )
)>output.txt
```

as a replacement to your original code:

```
@echo off
set str=
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type test.txt') do (
    if defined str echo %%i
    if "%%i" == "p q r" set str=1
 )
)>output.txt
```

and to include the search string.

```
@echo off
set str=
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type test.txt') do (
    if "%%i" == "p q r" set "str=1"
    if defined str echo %%i
 )
)>output.txt
```

Note that this will also remove any empty lines from the original file.

Comment: Gerhard, Its working as expected. But, One more question: what changes I have to do if it has to display the search string as well in both scenarios ?

Comment: So you want to include `p q r` in the result as well in this example, but nothing after?

Comment: Updated the answer for my example. to do so for your example, you'll need to take the count and -1. So between the 2 lines do `set /a line_no-=1`

Comment: also included another method for you to replace your original example for everything after string and one including search string

Comment: Cool. Worked great. Thank you Gerhard.  For the code which i have put in the description for inserting text after specific string, how to print the search string as well ?

Comment: See the last example I posted  as a replacement to all the code you posted and also for your current code see my second comment in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, filenames, 
rem and output filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q71800622.txt"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q71800622_2.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

SET "targetline=p q r"

:: Set these flags to Y for Yes or *nothing* for No (eg. SET "showbeforetarget=")
:: show??target will show that part of the first file
:: include...??insert will show the target line before/after the insert (or both)

SET "showbeforetarget=Y"
SET "showaftertarget=Y"
SET "includetargetbeforeinsert=Y"
SET "includetargetafterinsert=Y"

SET "targetfound="


(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 ECHO %%b|FINDSTR /x /L /C:"%targetline%" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  IF DEFINED showbeforetarget ECHO %%b
  IF DEFINED showaftertarget IF DEFINED targetfound ECHO %%b
 ) ELSE (
  SET "targetfound=Y"
  SET "showbeforetarget="
  IF DEFINED includetargetbeforeinsert ECHO %%b
  TYPE "%filename2%"
  IF DEFINED includetargetafterinsert ECHO %%b
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

This routine will allow a file to be inserted at the point where `findstr` finds a match (I've set it to `/x` exactly match the `/L` literal constant string shown as provided by OP).

It can be set to show/not show the portion before the target string, to show/not show the portion after the target string, and to show/not show the target string before or after the inserted lines (or both) from the second file.